# How do I pull a JSON file that is separate from a RESTFUL API's functions as an authenticated user via an API?

Tags: javascript, json, oauth

I need to simulate an authenticated user to pull a JSON file. I am using Last.fm's API, but there is currently no method to pull the specific data I want. If I just pull it as plain text in browser, it shows up. However, I want data that is specific to an authenticated user. So, if I login to Last.fm as me, then pull the data, the data is different than if I just pull the data from anywhere.

Basically, the data contained in this file is specific to the user, and as there is no function specifically set to access this file, I don't know how I'd do that....

My function that pulls the current data is listed below:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}


function getRadio() {
    var trackUrls = new Array();
    var resValue;
    var station;
    var radioStation;
    var url;
    var data;
    var neatDisplay;
    var resultsDisplay = document.getElementById('result');
    var radioTypeInput = document.getElementsByName('radioType');
    var queryInput = document.getElementById('query');
    var query = queryInput.value;
    for (var i = 0, length = radioTypeInput.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radioTypeInput[i].checked) {
            station = radioTypeInput[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (station == 1) {
        radioStation = "recommended";
    } else if (station == 2) {
        radioStation = "library";
    } else if (station == 3) {
        radioStation = "mix";
    } else {
        radioStation = "music";
    };
    if (radioStation != "music") {
        url = "https://crossorigin.me/" + "http://www.last.fm/player/station/user/" + query + "/" + radioStation;
    } else {
        url = "https://crossorigin.me/" + "http://www.last.fm/player/station/music/" + query;
    };
    console.log(url);
    request = createCORSRequest("get", url);
    if (request) {
        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                for (i = 0; i < data.playlist.length; i++) {
                    trackUrls[i] = data.playlist[i].playlinks[0].url;
                }
                neatDisplay = trackUrls.join("\n  ");
                resultsDisplay.innerHTML = neatDisplay;
                console.log(neatDisplay.toString());
                neatDisplay = neatDisplay.toString();
                return neatDisplay.toString();
            } else if (request.status == 503) {
                resultsDisplay.innerHTML = "Connection Error. The application may be overloaded."
            } else {}
        };
        request.onerror = function() {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Connection Error. The application may be overloaded. Try again later"
        };
        request.send();
    }
}
```

Ultimately, this used to pull Spotify links in the resulting data, but now it pulls YouTube. So, the problem only occurs if just pulling the file, without authentication.

Comment: Authentication requirements should be documented in their API docs are they not? How to use a specific API is really outside of the scope of this site unless I am misunderstanding the question

Comment: This has nothing to do with API specifics, I want to pull a URL as if I was a user logged into the site.

Comment: which site? The Last.FM site or your own? If it is the LAst.fm site then yes it is specific to their api authorization requirements

Comment: It shouldn't be specific to their API. Let me give you the scenario:
www.last.fm/player/station/user/jarjarfinks/recommended
Open that URL
You'll find there is a variable called "playlinks" with the sub-variable called "url." This URL is what I need. However, if you open that without a session from Last.fm, it shows YouTube links in that field.
Now, let's say you login to Last.fm. You go to that link again, it's Spotify links. This is only based on the current session, if you logout, it will do the YouTube links again. It's a basic JSON file available to ANY user

Comment: You're reformatted question is wrong, I am not using the Last.fm API at all in any way yet. It's purely pulling the text from the file I mentioned above

Comment: But you are using a proxy and that proxy won't have any of the cookies that would be needed at the api. You will not be able to do it this way and need to follow their API authentication requirments...period

Comment: Can you PM me? I am not even sure how I'd get those cookies to begin with is the problem.

Comment: You can't , cookies are domain specific. If their APi doesn't provide authentication requirements I don't know what to tell you other than using a CORS proxy that you don't control is not going to work

Comment: I'm new to OAuth and all this, so I guess I'm trying to figure out if I make a Auth call using their API method, without the CORS proxy, using a proper callback and all, does that store the session in such a way that would emulate what I'm talking about? There is no specific API call for this, but if I have the session like it would be in the browser, the data I want will be there

Comment: And what you need to know starts in their api docs . A quick look and I see there are also code libraries there as well and a section on authentication. You can't hack your way around it through a CORS proxy you don't control

Comment: I get that, you're getting the wrong idea. So, if I authenticate, using their API, returning a session, properly calling back to my app, rather than a CORS proxy, does that session allow me to grab that file as above (without proxy), as the user authenticated during auth? Does an API session token allow me to then pull the file (assuming the server allows me to do that) as the user I auth'd with?

Comment: I can't answer that without reading their docs, which i don't intend to do. There's a good chance you may need to pass all this through your own server. Goes right back to my very first comment that this is api specific and you need to read their docs thoroughly